# How do I fix the compiling errors in my program?

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program for school for the problem below.  Every time that I try to compile the program, it gives me compile errors that make no sense.  If anyone can help me figure out what the problem is, I would appreciate it.

Problem: A non-governmental organization needs a program to calculate the amount of financial assistance for needy families.  The formula is as follows:

-- If the annual household income is between $30,000 and $40,000 and the household has at least three children, the amount is $1,000 per child.

-- If the annual household income is between $20,000 and $30,000 and the household has at least two children, the amount is $1,500 per child.

-- If the annual household income is less than $20,000, the amount is $2,000 per child.

Implement a method for this computation. Write a program that asks for the household income and number of children for each applicant, printing the amount returned by your method.  Use -1 as a sentinel value for the input.

My program:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    /**
       This program computes the financial assistance that a family 
       can receive based on their income and the number of children.
*/

public class FinancialAidCalc
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

   /** This declares the variables 
          for the main method.
      */

      int income = 0;
      int children = 0;
      int financialAid = 0;


      /** This creates the method to request 
      the household income amount.
      @param income the amount of houshold income 
         that the user inputs
      @return the household income
      */

      public static int householdIncome(int income)
      {
         do
         {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Please enter the total household income.  Enter -1 to quit.");
         int income = in.nextInt();
         }
         while (income < -1);

         if (income >= 0) {return income;}
         if (income = -1) {return;}            
         }
      }



      /** This creates the method to request 
      the number of children in the household.
      @param children the number of children 
         in the houshold that the user inputs
      @return the number of children
      */

      public static int noOfHouseholdChildren(int children)
      {
         do
         {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Please enter the total number of children in the household.  Enter -1 to quit.");
         int children = in.nextInt();
         }
         while (children < -1);

         if (children >= 0) {return children;}
         if (children = -1) {return;}

      }   


      /** This method uses the returned results from the householdIncome and noOfHouseholdChildren
          methods in order to calculate the amount of financial assistance
          that a family will receive.
          @param financialAid shows the amount of financial aid that the family is eligible for

      */

      public static int availableFinancialAid(int income, int children)
      {
         /** This determines if the household income is between 
             $30,000 and $40,000 with at least 3 children.
         */

         if (income.isBetween(30000, 40000) && children >= 3)  
         {
            financialAid = (children * 1000);
            System.out.println("Your household income is: $" + income);
            System.out.println("You have " + children + " in your household.");
            System.out.println("Your household is eligible for $" + financialAid + "in financial aid.");
         }

         /** This determines if the household income is between 
             $20,000 and $30,000 with at least 2 children.
         */

         if (income.isBetween(20000, 30000) && children >= 2)  
         {
            financialAid = (children * 1500);
            System.out.println("Your household income is: $" + income);
            System.out.println("You have " + children + " in your household.");
            System.out.println("Your household is eligible for $" + financialAid + "in financial aid.");
         }

         /** This determines if the household income is less than $20,000..
         */

         if (income < 20000)   
         {
            financialAid = (children * 2000);
            System.out.println("Your household income is: $" + income);
            System.out.println("You have " + children + " in your household.");
            System.out.println("Your household is eligible for $" + financialAid + "in financial aid.");
         }

         /** This advises the user that they do not qualify for 
         financial aid if the income is over $40,000.
         */

         if (income > 40000) 
         {
            System.out.print("You do not qualify for financial aid.");
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us what errors you are getting. And we don't need the whole code (The error will tell you the line(s) with the problem; post the line(s) and code that is relevant to them). And we don't need to know the problem you are solving.

Comment: Let me guess: missing return statement in the `noOfHouseholdChildren` and `householdIncome` methods?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to declare methods inside a method. Look closely at the main method. You did not close the method, yet you are declaring other methods.

It seems as if you meant to create a class, then use it via the main method. In that case, you want something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinancialAidCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* code */
    }

    static int income = 0;
    static int children = 0;
    static int financialAid = 0;

    public static int householdIncome(int income) {
        /* code */
    }

    public static int noOfHouseholdChildren(int children) {
        /* code */
    } 

    public static int availableFinancialAid(int income, int children) {
       /* code */
    }
}
```

You may have other compile errors in your code, but due to the messiness, I didn't look closely.

Answer (score 2):

I see lines such as this

> if (income = -1)

I wonder if you really meant that. You can do assignments in conditionals in Java, but it's more likely that you meant this:

> if (income == -1)

Single equals sign is assignment, while double equals sign is equality test.

Comment: Good catch. The assignment surely creates a compile error, because `if (income = -1)` basically means `income = -1; if (-1)`, which is a syntax error.